# Tea father? Drink!

Tags: riddle

> I am a body thats for sure
>   Ire I held for my neighbours, so pure
>   My north teamed up while the south went solo
>   We remember the severe lack of the potato
>
> My symbol riddled with the need for peace
>   The war of the gods needed to cease
>   Green to the left, orange to the right
>   Fictional characters at the root of the spite

Comment: I have a guess that would match "orange to the left, green to the right" instead of "green to the left, orange to the right". Is the order really correct?

Comment: @VICTOR what was your guess?

Comment: I thought about Ireland, but the second verse make me think that it couldn't be (dammit!). Then I thought about Ivory Coast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> Ireland.

*I am a body thats for sure*

> one landmass

*Ire I held for my neighbours, so pure*

> "Ire" a clue for "Ireland", I guess...?

*My north teamed up while the south went solo*

> Northern Ireland versus Eire.

*We remember the severe lack of the potato*

> Potato famine

*My symbol riddled with the need for peace*

> ?

*The war of the gods needed to cease*

> Sectarian conflict

*Green to the left, orange to the right*

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ireland

*Fictional characters at the root of the spite*

> Jesus, Mary, God, etc... (although there is really a lot more than that forming the background of the Troubles, [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troubles#Background) [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantation_of_Ulster) [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Years%27_War_(Ireland)) [for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tudor_conquest_of_Ireland) [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromwellian_conquest_of_Ireland) [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Home_Rule_movement)...)

**Title:** *Tea father? Drink!*

> the incomparable [Father Ted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Ted), of course.

Comment: Ire as in rage, being in England I'm well aware of their rage, the IRA were a known force. IRE into irate into IRA also works. Irelands flag was to represent, now correct me if I'm wrong something to do with their celtish believe or protestants and the romans. Green for celts and orange for roman. White is the colour of peace therefore the division is peace

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, the flag is nationalism / peace / unionism, according to WP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flags_of_Ireland#Republic_of_Ireland

Comment: @Oblongamous - The **symbol** of Ireland is the Shamrock. Perhaps you meant the **standard**? (As a substitute for **flag** which would likely give it away a little too easily)

Comment: @JonStory a conventional representation of an object. If the irish flag isnt a representation of Ireland I dont know what is :D

Comment: It certainly is a representation and a "symbol" - but "The symbol" of Ireland (as suggested by "My Symbol" will make virtually anybody think of the shamrock. I'd also perhaps argue that it isn't "riddled" with white, either. "The Centre of my Standard, my desire for peace" or something to that effect, perhaps?

Comment: There are quite a few different things which symbolise Ireland. As well as the flag, I thought about the harp, Kathleen Ni Houlihan, Hibernai, the shamrock and the Celtic cross. I dismissed the leprechaun as being too corny. There's some more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:National_symbols_of_Ireland

Comment: @JonStory by personifying Ireland, its flag is his/hers. Also its no exactly riddled with anything apart from three colours. It was created to represent the desire for peace, each part of the flag representing a side with peace being the major theme of the flag. Therefore it has multiple references to peace ergo riddled.

Comment: That's a bit of a misnomer - the description of "Two sides and peace" was well after the adoption of the flag by the Easter Rising rebels: they didn't have a huge interest in peace! Either way, I'm not criticising the use of the flag in the riddle, just that I don't think many people will get it - almost anyone will associate "Symbol of Ireland" with the Shamrock.

Comment: That's what it seems to mean now though. "The white in the centre signifies a lasting truce between the 'Orange' and the 'Green'". [Department of the Taoiseach](http://www.taoiseach.gov.ie/eng/Historical_Information/The_National_Flag/) <--------- they ought to know.

Comment: Taoi, seach? Drink!